# Quality loss while using PIL.convert("RGBA")

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

### My Problem:

As soon as I convert the input **GIF** Image into a **RGBA** to process it, I'm enjoying quality loss on the image. (You can see the both pictures below the code)

The code shown below *"works"* just I don't got a clue, why i loose quality.
Any suggestions??

### My Code:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image as Im
from Tkinter import *

class App:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry('1171x900')

        self.maskPng = Im.open("Images/mask.gif")
        self.maskPng = self.maskPng.convert("RGBA")
        self.mask = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.maskPng)
        self.show = Canvas(self.root, width = 1170, height = 780)
        self.show.pack()
        self.show.create_image(0, 0, image = self.mask, anchor = NW)

        self.speedBTN = Button(self.root, text = "hello", command = self.speed).pack(side = "right")
        self.changed = False


    def speed(self):
        self.speedImg = Im.open("Images/speed/3_1.gif")
        self.speedImg = self.speedImg.convert("RGBA")
        self.maskPng.paste(self.speedImg, (0,0), self.speedImg)
        self.maskPng.save("Images/speed/test.gif", "GIF")
        self.render()

    def render(self):
        self.mask = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Im.open('Images/speed/test.gif'))
        self.show.create_image(0,0, image = self.mask, anchor = NW)
        self.show.image = self.mask

    def draw(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


main = App()

main.root.mainloop()
```

### Images:

This is my mask.gif:
[image: What it should look like]

---

This is my 3_1.gif:

(What it white on stackoverflow is transparent in the gif)
[image]

---

This is the grainy, harrowing result:

(I marked the most "grainy" areas with red rectangles)
[image]

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I would guess this issue has to do with the number of colors. GIF can use indexed colors. In your image there are a lot of subtly different shades of grey, and not many shades of colors, so this is a good match. RGBA however evenly distributes the colors it supports throughout the colorspace. You might see if there's an alternative color scheme available that has more fidelity in the areas you need (or just more fidelity overall!). I don't know anything about PIL's image processing, so I can't propose a specific solution.

Comment: You are saving the image as GIF again, which re-calculates the palette. The artefacts occur because the modification slightly changed color weighting (or perhaps PIL's color downsampling algorithm is different enough to always change it this way). Try saving as 24-bit color image -- does the issue disappear? I don't know if PIL allows modifying an indexed image without touching the palette.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue but I might have solution for your use case.

It doesn't seem like you actually do anything with the image so why don't you use the base64 encoded image and read it directly like below:

```
import Tkinter as tk # Python 2
import tkinter as tk # Python 3

# base64 encoded image data 
image = ''

root = tk.Tk()

# Pass the base64 encoded data directly to your PhotoImage() 
root.image = tk.PhotoImage(data=image)

# Display image in any way you need.
label = tk.Label(root, image=root.image, bg='white') 


root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("+250+250")
root.lift()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
root.wm_attributes("-disabled", True)
root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")
label.pack()
label.mainloop()
```

The question is old so it's unlikely that you are still working on this but I hope it will help someone else.

The issue seems to be only with RGBA, RGB works just fine but it obviously doesn't have Alpha channel. The code above will render image in its original form.

My problem is slightly different but relates to this issue. I'm trying to manipulate pixels so I have to load it as RGBA, process it and save again.

**Final Edit:**

After filling the issue report on github I got reply from the author.
https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3059

The relevant part is :

> It's quantization issue. 
>   This gives the same result:
>
> ```
> (Image.open('./37943912.gif')
>     .convert('RGBA')
>     .quantize()
>     .save('_out.png'))
> ```

This is now verified and should be considered a final answer.